# Regex for contained path

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
"Invalid value of \"parameter\" set for \"goodProfile[1]/betterProfile[1]/bestrProfile[1]\". Nearest valid value is \"FollowInput.\""
```

I need a regex accepting this string as well as all strings that contain the substring `goodProfile[...]/betterProfile[...]/bestrProfile[...]`
where the string in the brackets has to be a number.

Since I'm not very experienced with Regexes, I'm getting a little lost.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
goodProfile\[[0-9]+\]\/betterProfile\[[0-9]+\]\/bestrProfile\[[0-9]+\]
```